# What is the maximum skill bonus that can be crafted into a magic item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I know that a weapon enchantment caps out at +10 or 200K GP value.  But what about skill increasing items?  It seems pretty cheap to get a +10 ring of Jump. (10,000 GP)
I remember reading something in a forum somewhere where pre-epic skill boosts can be up to +30. Is this true?  After that is it just a x10 price jump or am I missing something?  Please provide book title and page references so that I can support this crafting attempt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Either a +44 or a +30, depending on the type of bonus.

[Magic Item Basics](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/magicItems/basics.htm)

> - Grants an enhancement bonus on a skill check greater than +30.
> - Has a market price above 200,000 gp, not including material costs for armor or weapons, material component- or experience point-based costs, or additional value for intelligent items.

[Creating Magic Items with Competence Bonuses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm)

There is a formula for computing the price to create a magic item. Since non-epic magic items have a price below 200,000, use the following formula:

44 x 44 x 100 gp = 193,600 gp.

---

**Conclusion**

There are no maximums specifically mentioned for a competence bonus, as there are for enhancement bonuses. The maximum would be limited by gold costs to create. In the realm of enhancement bonuses, there is a maximum stated.

- Competence Maximum: +44
- Enhancement Maximum: +30

---

**Fun Fact**

Competence Bonuses Stack with Enhancement Bonuses. So, a +44 Ring of Lies (Bluff), a +30 Ring of False Truths (Bluff), and a casting of the spell Glibness (+30 untyped), would give you, with no other factors involved, a +104 to Bluff. You can trust Bards... right?

Comment: Why do you say there's no maximums for competence bonuses, then provide a competence maximum? What has the price got to do with the maximum you provided, if there is any relationship? What's the price formula you provided before; is that something related to your first or second link? Your answer needs _a lot_ more explaining of the things you're quoting and stating.

Comment: @doppelgreener There is not a maximum as far as a specific number is concerned (such as enhancement bonuses), it is a maximum set by price. A non-epic item is a price below 200,000 gold. Come on...

Comment: Which is stuff I didn't know, and which you didn't state previously. That _did_ need explaining, and your answer had very little explanation, so when someone requests clarification, please don't "come on" them. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: But if one's willing to pay the epic ×10 price for a magic item granting a greater than +44 competence bonus or +30 enhancement bonus, one could? I mean, one would have to be, like, a truenamer to *want* to, but one *can*, right?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The Epic Wondrous Item Chart show enhancement bonuses to ability scores up to +12, and armor up to +15. The Boots of Swiftness gives a +20 competence bonus to 4 different skills. Yet, there is no specific mention of a maximum for epic level magic items. Since a Ring of Universal Ring of Energy Immunity costs 2+ million gold; DM Fiat would be required? If an epic character had the means, and a DM allowing it to have an Amulet of Truespeak +200... The rules don't seem to say you can't, but that doesn't mean he should. Remember the video about Sneak Attacking with a Ballista?

Comment: [I am familiar with the ballista backstab.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69392/8610) And somebody asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98619/8610) that saw me to do some *EL* research myself.

Answer (score -1):

There are Wondrous items like the [Salve of Slipperiness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#salveofSlipperiness) granting +20 to Escape Artist checks.  There are also armor special abilities like [Greater Shadow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#shadowGreater) granting +15 to certain skill checks.  Greater than +10 is easily possible in the core rules.

Other than those specific examples, the only explicit rules are the limits on item price and Wealth by Level guidelines.  You will need to design custom magic items for this, though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie-The reference to the other answer was meant as little more than a parenthetical note, but I see what you mean. I'll edit to hopefully improve the clarity of my answer

Comment: You may get the downvotes removed if you edit this answer to more clearly address the question. He is asking about what maximum bonuses are/could be, not what magic items provide bonuses. The items in your answer could be good references for "an aside."

Answer (score -1):

NoctyNightshade said, in his answer:

> I think the creator must have at least as many ranks in that check or be able to cast a spell that makes the effect.
>
> So I would say +20 is the max. (If not epic)

I think that's correct.  You need some way of providing the skills to make the item.  It says in the rules to check for specific requirements.

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm

On the page it links to the cloak of elvenkind as an example.
Looking at that item you will see to get the +5 competence bonus.  You need the spell invisibility.  This means there is some kind of requirement beyond the standard gold and xp.

So yes.  You either need to have the skill ranks yourself, or you need a spell to somehow replicate the effect.  44 is not possible with the current rules.  Even 30 is only possible with jump thanks to the spell of the same name. (As far as I remember)

edit: and glibness as a spell for bluff.  I am sure there are others but the cap would be 30.  That is if you took a straight spell to item transfer which i think would be broken.  Even the cloak of elvenkind doesn't give a straight 1 to 1 from invisibility to the cloak's power.

Comment: If your intention is to comment on another answer, you should leave it as a comment on that answer. The rest of your answer does seem to independently answer the question, so you may want to rephrase the answer to stand on its own.

Comment: I would if the website didn't require karma to do so.  That is also why i gave a complete answer so it stood on it's own.  Also thanks tiggerous for the edit.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Even in the core rules there are magic items that grant skill bonuses that do *not* have as creation prerequisites possession of 1 or more ranks in the skill. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59063/8610) cites two, for instance. Your answer may want to address those cases, too. Thank you for participating and for trying to help strangers!

Comment: You mention *cloak of elvenkind*, but I see absolutely nothing that says a *cloak of elvenkind* requires 5 ranks in Hide to create—its requirements only say you need to be an elf with Craft Wondrous Items and the ability to cast *invisibility*; no skills of any kind are mentioned.

Comment: Hey i can chan - you are right the first one doesn't.  The first one is a single use items that grants a temporary bonus. The original question was about actual permanent magical enchantments.  The second one greater shadow does indeed require invisibility.

Comment: KRyan- it doesn't require skill points for the cloak but my point is you need something to get that bonus from.  If there is no spell then you need something else.  Copying someone's skill magically to place in an item makes sense.  Just creating a +10 item from gold and xp doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

I think the creator must have at least as many ranks in that check or be able to cast a spell that makes the effect.

So I would say +20 is the max. (If not epic)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You've probably noticed that your answer has received some downvotes; taking the [tour] will probably clear up why. While it's sometimes fine to speculate, an answer to a question like this should cite sources to back it up or explain how a house rule's worked out in campaigns you've been in. Sorry you weren't welcomed earlier. Thank you for participating and trying to help strangers.