# Are there methods to get high Unopposed skill bonuses?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, skills, psionics

**Is there anything that can apply a +25 or better bonus to an unopposed Skill check?**

(preferably a power or magical item that can be applied to any/another character, but not an absolute requirement)

If not, what is the highest single modifier to an unopposed skill check that can be applied to a single roll? (universally *applied to any skill*, not a specific skill like climbing or knowledge:arcana)

So I started working on a character build for higher level and then I reread something about [*Moment of Prescience*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/momentOfPrescience.htm), which is available to both spellcasters and psionic classes. The sentence that threw me was here:

> This spell grants you an insight bonus equal to your caster level
>   (maximum +25) on any single attack roll, opposed ability or skill
>   check, or saving throw.

When I first read it, I read it like this

> This spell grants you an insight bonus equal to your caster level
>   (maximum +25) on any single attack roll, opposed ability, **or skill
>   check**

but the grammar indicates the opposed also belongs to the "or skill check" and doesn't stop at ability. Meaning this power, while great for combat and saving throws, is actually worthless for skills with a static DC.

I've seen reroll powers (average +5, but no change in max), feats (+2-3), and psionic shards (+1-10 once).

Comment: There are *many* ways to increase a creature's skill modifiers—far too many to list, actually. I *like* list questions, but you gotta narrow the request. Are you looking for spells, psionic powers, mundane items, magic items, feats, or some other category? Then, also, probably *what skill?* I've voted to put this question on hold as *Too Broad* until its narrowed so you can get the *exact* answer what you want, but feel free to ask multiple questions about this topic.

Comment: The grammar _what_? I'd never read that Oxford comma to signify "opposed [ability or skill check]". O.o

Comment: Zachiel, if it is true that the skill check can be applied using Moment of Prescience, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: [Related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59060/8610)

Answer (score 1):

**Divine Insight**

One of my favourites is divine insight (Spell Compendium, page 70). Which is a lv 2 cleric/paladin spell. It lasts for 1 hour/lv, and gives a one time bonus of 5+CL(max 15) as an immediate action to any skill check.

Comment: while my character build isn't a cleric, that +15 is the current closest to replacing the +25 from Moment of Prescience. Good job!

Comment: You can add it to your list with 2 lv's of Unseer Seer. Which is located in Complete Mage. This may seem expensive, but the class isn't too bad.